# React js Delay rendering causes error

Tags: reactjs

I have form where I should render one of elements in a while. I use `setTimeout` for this aim in `componentDidMount` but I get warning `setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.`

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        this.state = {resend: false};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const max = 3;

        if (this.props.count < max) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({resend: true});
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                ...
                {this.state.resend ? <Component/> : null}
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component is probably unmounting at some point, then the timeout finishes, and it attempts to call setState after your component is no longer being rendered.

You need to cancel any timeouts you have running in `componentWillUnmount`. Store a reference to them and delete them.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        this.state = {resend: false};
        this.timeouts = [];
    }

    componentWillUnmount(props, context) {
        this.timeouts.forEach(t => window.clearTimeout(t));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const max = 3;

        if (this.props.count < max) {
            const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({resend: true});
            }, 1000);
            this.timeouts.push(timeoutId);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                ...
                {this.state.resend ? <Component/> : null}
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the component doesn't exist when the setTimeout calls. Use a mounted flag to see if the component still exists.

```
constructor(props, context) {
  this.state = {resend: false};
  this.mounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.mounted = false;
}

componentDidMount() {
  const max = 3;

  if (this.props.count < max) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!this.mounted) return;
      this.setState({resend: true});
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```